# Can I edit a TLV file using a perl script?

Tags: perl, edit, tlv

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to edit/add parameters to a TLV* file because I have no idea if a solution exists and how to go about it. Thank you.

A tlv file (extension .bin file) is an emta configuration file defined by docsis.

Comment: Perhaps if you explained what a "TLV file" is, people might be better able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course create your own DOCSIS-file parser/manipulater in Perl (or whatever language). My advise is not to re-invent the wheel and use http://docsis.sourceforge.net/ as a basis for your needs.

Another approach could be to use http://www.excentis.com/product.php?product_id=7 (Free, but closed source AFAIK)